# EditText case sensitive

Tags: android, if-statement, android-edittext, case-sensitive

```
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
 Case R.id.ibGo:
    String str = et.getText().toString();
        if (str.contentEquals("password")){
            Intent levelTwo = new Intent (
                "com.xxx.xxx.LEVELTWO");
            startActivity(levelTwo);
        } else if (str.contentEquals("music")){

            Intent levelFour = new Intent (
                "com.xxx.xxx.LEVELFOUR");
            startActivity(levelFour);  
        } else {
            vib.vibrate(300);
            iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        break;
```

When i write "password" in the edittext in the emulator, the emulator works as expected. But when i (for example) write "Passwords"(Capital P) the application stops unexpectedly.

What can I do to make it not fail on capital letters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings are case sensitive.

Instead of

```
if (str.contentEquals("password")){
//do something
}
```

DO THIS!!

```
if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("password")){
//do something
}
```

Comment: Do you have any ideas on how i can make the keyboard on my emulator go away after pressing the button?

Comment: Make sure you accept an answer and upvote if you can. This keeps the community going.

Answer (score 2):

I think your question and your problem are two different things, so:

> What can I do to make it not react to capital letters, ways to make it not case sensetive?

You can use `equalsIgnoreCase` (`str.equalsIgnoreCase("password")`) to make the comparison case insensitive, but I think your problem is here:

> But when i for example write "Passwords"(Capital P) the application stops unexpectedly..

This is probably due to a problem in the `else` block, seems like either `vib` or `iv` are null.

Comment: Thank you, i'm pretty new to this stuff so you actually solved my problem and made me realize i had a little bug in my "else" statement...

Comment: Do you have any ideas on how i can make the keyboard on my emulator go away after pressing the button?